# Is there a simple way to compile an sbt project with Dotty?

Tags: scala, sbt, dotty

Now that Dotty is apparently getting ready to compile larger projects, I wonder if there is a simple way to use it as drop-in replacement for Scalac in sbt projects? Like if I had the following `build.sbt`:

```
name := "Foo"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
```

Are there some steps I can take to swap out Scalac for Dotc here?

Comment: I don't know for sure that this isn't supported yet, but I notice that "Work on SBT integration of the compiler" is listed as a to-do-item at http://www.scala-lang.org/blog/2015/10/23/dotty-compiler-bootstraps.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We've merged [#2344 Make sbt aware of Dotty](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/pull/2344) feature contributed by Guillaume Martres, and it will be part of 0.13.10.
In the meantime you can try it with the nightly published to https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/.